# How can I set the sample rate/frequency for a Webots GPS module?

Tags: gps, ros2, webots, urdf

I'm trying to simulate a GPS module I have on a real robot (using ROS 2) which has a position update rate of 1Hz. Is it possible to set this in a GPS device? I'm importing the device directly to Webots from a URDF (I had to modify the urdf2webots script to include the GPS() device), but I can't find a sample_rate option in Webots so I can change that too.

These are the only settings available (this one was imported from URDF):

[image]

None of these options seem to affect sample-rate for just the GPS.

Is my only option to write a ROS node that captures the 30Hz Webots sim rate and only republishes at the desired rate? Or can this be set in Webots somehow?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webots the sensor update rate is defined in the controller side when enabling the device by specifying the sampling period in ms (1Hz = 1000ms) and not in the model definition.

For the [GPS](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/gps) device, here is the documentation of the enable function:
https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/gps#wb_gps_enable

If you are using ROS, then the update rate is specified using the sampling period value using the `webots_ros::set_int` argument of the [`/<device_name>/enable` service](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/gps?tab-language=ros#wb_gps_enable).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*